# Data Extraction form JDBC response in Jmeter (DB Result)

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I am raising a JDBC request and getting a data from DB successfully. Now I want to extract values from column and want to pass it to new request as parameter. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As per [JDBC Request Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request):

> If the Variable Names list is provided, then for each row returned by a Select statement, the variables are set up with the value of the corresponding column (if a variable name is provided), and the count of rows is also set up. For example, if the Select statement returns 2 rows of 3 columns, and the variable list is A,,C, then the following variables will be set up:

> ```
> A_#=2 (number of rows)
> A_1=column 1, row 1
> A_2=column 1, row 2
> C_#=2 (number of rows)
> C_1=column 3, row 1
> C_2=column 3, row 2
> ```

So define a Variable Name per each column and you will get a separate [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) per each row

More information: [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)